# Github - create a new folder in existing project

Tags: git, github, repository, branch, git-branch

I see I can "Create a new file here" button (the plus button) on the github page in my existing project in any folder. 
However, how can I create a new folder in existing project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [git does not track empty directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1860929), and so if you are trying to create  an empty directory in your project on github, that won't be possible, because it is just not supported by git.

If on the other hand, you want to create a file within a new directory, you can simply input its file name as `directory/filename` and github will create a folder named directory for you.

Answer (score 0):

As described on GitHub's [help page](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-new-files) for creating new files, if you type a `/` in the new filename, it will create a subdirectory.